# Extraction of XML Data using Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to create a JSON file containing extracted data of Goodreads XML file, but I am unable to do so. I have never worked with XML and I have tried to go through tutorials but to no avail, I am not able to extract any data.

My XML File looks like this:

```
  <books_count type="integer">11</books_count>
  <original_publication_year type="integer">1997</original_publication_year>
  <original_publication_month type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <original_title>There Was an Old Lady Who Swallowed a Fly</original_title>
<popular_shelves>
      <shelf name="to-read" count="3504"/>
      <shelf name="picture-books" count="397"/>
      <shelf name="childrens" count="226"/>
      <shelf name="children-s-books" count="213"/>
      <shelf name="children" count="149"/>
      <shelf name="children-s" count="139"/>
      <shelf name="caldecott" count="110"/>
</pouplar_shelves>
```

How to extract the data and specifically from popular shelves as the data I require is in shelf name?

Edit1:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
path = "books_xml"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    print(tree)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        print(child.books_count, child.text)
```

This is what i was trying to do, I have to run by multiple xml files in a directory. It throws error:

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'books_count'
```

Edit2:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('sample_book.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
print(myroot)
name = myroot.find('original_title').text
print(name)
```

Giving the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What tutorials? Where is your attempt to do this and what is the specific problem with it? Give a [mre].

Comment: Can we see your code so far? Any attempts at all?

Comment: Look into lxml or libxml

Comment: I am sorry, I added the code I was working with

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added the codes, that I was working with. I hope it gives you the insight of the problem and can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here you find all examples for a basic extraction

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

2nd, your xml needs be better structured: E.g "pouplar_shelves" is typo error

3nd, I'll give you a small example

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<popular_shelves>
      <shelf name="to-read" count="3504"/>
      <shelf name="picture-books" count="397"/>
      <shelf name="childrens" count="226"/>
      <shelf name="children-s-books" count="213"/>
      <shelf name="children" count="149"/>
      <shelf name="children-s" count="139"/>
      <shelf name="caldecott" count="110"/>
</popular_shelves>
'''

xml_root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for i in xml_root.iter():
    print(i.tag, i.attrib)
```

As result:

```
popular_shelves {}
shelf {'name': 'to-read', 'count': '3504'}
shelf {'name': 'picture-books', 'count': '397'}
shelf {'name': 'childrens', 'count': '226'}
shelf {'name': 'children-s-books', 'count': '213'}
shelf {'name': 'children', 'count': '149'}
shelf {'name': 'children-s', 'count': '139'}
shelf {'name': 'caldecott', 'count': '110'}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Edit:

You should understand better what I've sent in docs Python. Also, be familiar with the source code of ET

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py

This is the model

```
Example form:
        <tag attrib>text<child/>...</tag>tail
```

By using shelf as example:

```
for i in xml_root.iter('shelf'):
    print(i.attrib)
```

Will return this:

```
{'name': 'to-read', 'count': '3504'}
{'name': 'picture-books', 'count': '397'}
{'name': 'childrens', 'count': '226'}
{'name': 'children-s-books', 'count': '213'}
{'name': 'children', 'count': '149'}
{'name': 'children-s', 'count': '139'}
{'name': 'caldecott', 'count': '110'}
```

Bcz your XML tag is shelf and your atribs is name and count
 is translated
text...tail

Comment: Thanks! I was able to extract the genres, but the other fields are returned as author {}
id {}
name {}
link {}
book {}
id {}
title {}

When I try to iter it by passing it in xml_root.iter('title') it is returning title{} title{} title{}

Comment: Thanks! Means a lot